# Should we provide form navigation in 2 step forms?

Tags: website-design, forms, web

It is said that multi-step forms should have form navigation in them. But is it also needed in 2-step forms?

[image: First step in the two step form]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You want to know if in the last step of a multistep process you should add a back option, links to the other steps or breadcrumbs?

Comment: No Madalina. My question is whether I should tell the user beforehand that there are two steps in this form when there are only two steps. If I do so, wouldn't it mean providing excess information? Nevertheless, Pavel Ryzhov has a point. We should still providethe navigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Yes, the number of steps should be clearly indicated.*

When a user fills up a form, he or she doesn't know that there are just two forms. Such awareness affects positively on user's decision whether or not to proceed with filling up a form.

If the steps are small and can be combined, perhaps, it can be an even better option. In this case, don't forget to update the title of the button from "Next" to "Finish", that will indicate that the form contains no additional steps.

Comment: Hey Pavel, can you share any references e.g. books, studies, or online blogs that talk about two-step forms? I too feel the same but am struggling to find any way to convince my team.

Comment: @VineetArora, I'd love to, but this answer based only on my own experience as a user, thus there is no external source.